# If $\int_{|z|=1} z^n f(z)dz=0 \ \forall n = 0, 1, 2, ...$, then $f$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

> True or false: $f$ holomorphic in $A=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: 0\lt |z|\lt 2\}$ and $\int_{|z|=1} z^n f(z)dz=0 \ \forall n = 0, 1, 2, ...$ then $f$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$.

I' m not sure if this is true or false because I can only prove that $f$ is either analytic at zero or has a removable singularity.

$f$ holomorphic in $A$ means that we can express $f$ as a Laurent series of the form

$$f(z)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{b_n}{z^n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n}{z^n}$$

with 
$$a_n = \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac {f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz$$

$$b_n = \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{\gamma} {f(z)}{z^{n-1}}dz$$

$\int_{|z|=1} z^n f(z)dz=0 \ \forall n = 0, 1, 2, ...$ means that $b_n = 2 \pi i \cdot 0 = 0 \ \forall n$, so $f$ has as worst a removable singularity at $z=0$.

Now to prove that $f$ has indeed a removable singularity one must prove that $f$ is not analytic at $z=0$. But $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n}{z^n}$ at $A$, so for $f$ not to be analytic at $z=0$ we must have that $f(0) \neq a_0=  \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac {f(z)}{z}dz$, which I haven't been able to prove.

Comment: I think any entire $f$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @user658409 Changing to $f\equiv 1$, you might just as well ask why $\frac zz$ isn't a counterexample. But that's an archetypal example of a function with a removable singularity. The answer is that the domain of $f$ has a puncture in it, and that puncture is a singularity. But there is a value you could assign to $f$ at that puncture to make the function analytic, and that makes the singularity removable.

Comment: First, as already pointed out you're confused about the definition of "removable singularity". Less to the point, since $f$ is only defined for $0<|z|<2$ it's _not_ analytic at the origin - it can't be, since $f(0)$ is undefined! It's an _extension_ of $f$ that's analytic at $0$ (which of course is precisely what it means to say $f$ has a removable singularity...)

Comment: @NitinUniyal What's the _definition_ of "removable singularity"?

Comment: @David C.Ulrich..A singularity at $z=a$ is removable if there is no negative powers of $(z-a)$ in Laurent's expansion of $f(z)$.

Comment: @NitinUniyal I wouldn't really call that the _definition_, but it's a true fact. Now why would an entire function be a counterexample? If $f$ is entire there are no negative powers  of $(z-a)$ in the Laurent expansion about $a$.

Comment: Yes...as the question doesn't assures that $z=0$ is a singularity of $f(z)$. It only states that $f$ is analytic in annular disc.

Comment: @NitinUniyal There is no definition, as far as I know, of "$z=0$ is a singularity of $f$".

Comment: @NitinUniyal The actual correct standard definition is this: "Let $A=\{z:0<|z-a|<r\}$. Suppose $f$ is analytic in $A$. Then $f$ has a removable singularity at $a$ if there exists a function $g$ analytic in $D(a,r)$ with $g|_A=f$." That is the definition. And it doesn't say anything about whether or not "$a$ is a singularity".

Comment: @NitinUniyal You need to fix the typos before I can answer that.

Comment: @David C. Ulrich..my point of confusion is: "If $f$ is holomorphic in punctured unit disc $D$-{0} then is it necessary that $f$ has a singularity at $z=0$?"

Comment: @NitinUniyal I can't answer that unless you give me the definition of "$f$ has a singularity at $z=0$. As I said above, I'm not aware that that has a standard definition.

Comment: Yes I understood the formal definition and according to this $f$ can't be entire then. Am I correct?

Comment: What seems that defining a holomorphic $f$ except the point $z=a$ is sufficient to conclude that the point is removable singularity.

Comment: @NitinUniyal"Yes I understood the formal definition and according to this $f$ can't be entire then. Am I correct? " I'm not sure because your question for two reasons: (i) When you say "$f$ can't be entire" do you mean "If $f$ has a removable singulairty then $f$ can't be entire"? (ii) Given the sloppy way you've been using various words I'm actually not certain what you mean by "$f$ is entire". Example: Say  $A=\{0<|z|<2\}$ and $f:A\to\Bbb C$ is defined by $f(z)=0$. **Q:** In your terminology, **is** $f$ entire?

Comment: @DavidCUllrich..For $f$ to be entire, it needs to be defined for all $z\in \mathbb C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation of removable singularity is not the accepted one. You are not required to prove that $f$ is **not** analytic at $0$. For example $f(z)=0$ for all $z \neq 0$ has a removable singularity at $0$.

Answer (score 2):

To expand a bit on Kavi's answer: Say $A=\{z:0<z<2\}$ and assume $f\in H(A)$.

You're concerned that $f$ may be analytic at the origin. Of course Kavi is exactly right when he says "so what?". But the situation has a curious aspect.

First, speaking carefully,

(i) $f$ is analytic at the origin

is impossible, because strictly speaking $f(0)$ is undefined. The sensible, formally correct version of (i) is

(ii) It's possible to define $f(0)$ in such a way that $f$ becomes analytic at the origin.

And here's the reason I'm posting this: Not only is (ii) no problem regarding whether $f$ has a removable singularity, in fact (ii) is precisely the *definition* of "$f$ has a removable singularity"!

So when you say "I can only prove $f$ has a removable singularity or (i)" you're really saying "I can only prove $f$ has a removable singularity or (ii)", and *by definition* that means you're saying this:

> > I can only prove $f$ has a removable singularity or $f$ has a removable singularity.

**Moral:** You need to *know* the definitions.

Comment: for some reason I assumed $f$ defined in $A \cup \{ 0 \} $ and analytic in $A$ and thought that I could somehow infer $f(0)$ from the integral equality... so yeah, I should have paid more attention to what the question actually said.

Answer (score 0):

You are right: we have that $b_n=0$ for all $n \ge 1$ and therefore

$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n}{z^n}$ on $A$. Now define $g(z):= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n}{z^n}$ for $|z|<2.$ Then $g$ is holomorphic and $g$ is a holomorphic continuation of $f$ on the disc $|z|<2.$

Conclusion: $f$ has a removable singularity at $z=0.$

Comment: @user658409 Huh? If you know what a removable singularity _is_ then it's utterly obvious that the function $f=0$ has a removable singularity. If you don't know what a removable singularity is you should look it up.

Comment: Of course this exactly correct, but it seems sort of beside the point. The OP appears to have got this far on his own; what you say here says nothing about what he's confused about, that is "Now to prove that $f$ has indeed a removable singularity one must prove that $f$ is not analytic at $z=0$. "